# node exporter can not bind the port

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

My node exporter was installed using kubernetes daemonset. The default port of node exporter is 9100, but the port on my local machine is already occupied, So I modify the config file serveral times to change the port. But it failed every time. the following config was what I have tried:
tryied times 1(modify the 9100 port to 19100):

```
containers：
- name: prometheus-node-exporter
  image: "docker.ssiid.com/prom/node-exporter:v0.18.1"
  imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
  args:
    - --path.procfs=/host/proc
    - --path.sysfs=/host/sys
  ports:
    - name: metrics
      containerPort: 19100
      hostPort: 19100
  volumeMounts:
    - name: proc
      mountPath: /host/proc
      readOnly:  true
    - name: sys
      mountPath: /host/sys
      readOnly: true
```

the result is does't work. It's still using port 9100 from the log

tried times 2(add new option to args - --web.listen-address=":9100") like below:

```
containers:
- name: prometheus-node-exporter
  image: "docker.ssiid.com/prom/node-exporter:v0.18.1"
  imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
  args:
    - --web.listen-address=":19100"
    - --path.procfs=/host/proc
    - --path.sysfs=/host/sys
  ports:
    - name: metrics
      containerPort: 9100
      hostPort: 9100
  volumeMounts:
    - name: proc
      mountPath: /host/proc
      readOnly:  true
    - name: sys
      mountPath: /host/sys
```

it still does not work. the error like this:

```
time="2020-03-13T10:56:03Z" level=info msg=" - time" source="node_exporter.go:104"
time="2020-03-13T10:56:03Z" level=info msg=" - timex" source="node_exporter.go:104"
time="2020-03-13T10:56:03Z" level=info msg=" - uname" source="node_exporter.go:104"
time="2020-03-13T10:56:03Z" level=info msg=" - vmstat" source="node_exporter.go:104"
time="2020-03-13T10:56:03Z" level=info msg=" - xfs" source="node_exporter.go:104"
time="2020-03-13T10:56:03Z" level=info msg=" - zfs" source="node_exporter.go:104"
time="2020-03-13T10:56:03Z" level=info msg="Listening on \":19100\"" source="node_exporter.go:170"
time="2020-03-13T10:56:03Z" level=fatal msg="listen tcp: address tcp/19100\": unknown port" source="node_exporter.go:172"
```

How to change the port?

Answer (score 1):

the following config is effective:

```
containers:
- name: prometheus-node-exporter
  image: "docker.ssiid.com/prom/node-exporter:v0.18.1"
  imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
  args:
    - --web.listen-address=localhost:19100
    - --path.procfs=/host/proc
    - --path.sysfs=/host/sys
  ports:
    - name: metrics
      containerPort: 19100
```